# problem mounting ntfs drive automatically

Tags: 12.04, wubi, ntfs, automount

i have a few ntfs drives which i want ubuntu to auto-mount, as a sample i tried it for 1 drive
i included this line in "fstab"

```
/dev/sda2      /home/tejas/Tejas!   ntfs    users,defaults,umask=000 0 0
```

and it doesnt get automounted...
when i mount it manually i get the following message

> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
>   Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE
>   library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated
>   FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at
>   http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged

i am using ubuntu 12.04 in wubi
Can someone tell how i can mount it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [link](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged) from your error message, following should be valid:

1. ntfs-3g is compiled with integrated FUSE support
2. the ntfs-3g binary is at least version 1.2506
3. the ntfs-3g binary is set to setuid-root
4. the user has access right to the volume
5. the user has access right to the mount point

It looks like your mount folder has a bad name (5). Use `/home/tejas/Tejas\!` instead.

---

But personally, I'd advise you couple of things:

- to move your mount point outside of home folder, i.e. `/ntfs` or `/windows`
- do not use special characters in file and folder names

Both of these suggestions has hidden pros.

Comment: thanks for the reply.... it has mounted to folder '/Windows'
but it doesnt show up on sidebar anymore......     
its rather like a folder, wot to make it appear in there?

Comment: Glad it helped. Please approve the answer :)

Comment: i am sorry o bother again but i just put the line 
'/dev/sda5      /Tejas     ntfs users,defaults,umask=000 0 0  '
and the folder '/Tejas ' seems to be empty and it is not shown in side pane of nautilus
also when i type 'sudo blkid' in terminal i seem to be getting 5 ntfs drives whereas i have only 4(other than the host drive)

Comment: Please post output of `sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: `sudo blkid

/dev/loop0: UUID="e4631286-53ba-43e0-9fc7-fb34a581163c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="5AB05E83B05E6613" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="C4C85C20C85C12D2" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="suhas" UUID="46CC8EA8CC8E91BB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Tejas" UUID="58284D59284D36F2" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Tejas" UUID="F6D071D4D0719B95" TYPE="ntfs"`
and

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
224 heads, 19 sectors/track, 229504 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1d0f016e`

Comment: `Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    84092927    41943040    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        84092928   126033919    20970496    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       126035968   976771071   425367552    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       126038016   545468415   209715200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       545470464   976769023   215649280    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

Comment: According to that info, you have 5 NTFS partitions on that drive, last two are placed within extended partition (because there can be only 4 primary+extended partitions in total): 1, 2, 3 - primary NTFS, 4 - extended, parent of 5 & 6 NTFS. Basically, you can try mounting all those partitions as NTFS except `/dev/sda4`, and check what's inside. Most likely `/dev/sda1` is a small 50Mb Windows boot/rescue partition, which you can ignore as well.